# AngularJS + PHP: Como os dados devem ser consumidos?

Tags: php, angularjs, web-service

Iniciando algumas leituras sobre o [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) para um possível projeto futuro, me veio à mente algumas dúvidas quanto a integração do cliente/servidor e o consumo dos dados disponibilizados pelo servidor.

Como deve ser feito isso? Através de [REST](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST), ou há outra forma?

Comment: também tenho esta dúvida. Não sei desenvolver com angular, mas desenvolvo com back end e preciso saber alguma coisa sobre o angular para integrar com o back end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Como deve ser feito isso? Através de REST, ou há outra forma?

Você precisa ter uma API (na maioria dos casos é usado REST, mas eu já vi com SOAP) que será consumida no seu aplicativo **Angular**. Quem irá fazer a conexão com banco de dados, regra de negócio e afins será a API, o aplicativo **Angular** se preocupará apenas em enviar requisições para a API.

Basicamente você vai desenvolver, manter e publicar o *backend* separado do seu *frontend*.

**Sobre o desenvolvimento e consumo de APIs REST**

O próprio Angular provê recursos para consumo de serviços REST, como o *service* [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) e o [`ngResource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) e existem alguns *frameworks* PHP que podem te ajudar a desenvolvedor sua API REST como o [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) e o [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/).

---

Um exemplo, bem simples de como é consumir uma API REST usando [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```js
function HelloWorld($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://restservice.com:1233/HelloWorld').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.hello = data;
       });
}
```

Comment: Dei uma lida sobre o Slim, atualmente utilizo CakePHP. Então REST é a melhor opção de se trabalhar com AngularJS?

Comment: Bom, ai entra um pouco de opinião e a minha opinião é que sim, REST é a melhor opção pra se trabalhar com Angular.