# Angular2 Enviar e receber informaçoes

Tags: angular

Bom pessoal estou aprendendo a usar o `Angular 2` porém tenho uma dúvida.

Andei procurando na internet e me falaram que seria bom criar um servidor `NodeJs` pra receber e enviar dados para o servidor `mysql` fazendo com que o `socket.io` fizesse o trabalho do `php`.

É isso mesmo ou está errado? Continuo usando o `http.post` e `http.get`?

Comment: [Isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90351/18246) responde sua pergunta?

Comment: caso querira que o dado sera real time ai sim uso o soket ne

Comment: Depende com quais linguagens você trabalha. Caso trabalhe com java por exemplo, ataque com Spring framework e seja feliz.